# Notification not working on Multiple guards

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have 2 guards. One 'user' and the other 'admin'.

I have stored notification in database as admin. But guard('admin') is not working.

Here is my code in blade file:

```
<span class="badge badge-light">{{count(auth()->guard('admin')->user()->unreadNotifications())}}</span>
```

But i am only getting '1' as a result. I have 6 records in my table. Also my forech loop is not working either with guard. Here is the code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @foreach(auth()->guard('admin')->user()->notifications() as $notifications)
                           <li>{{$notifications->type}}</li>
                        @endforeach
</ul>
```

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `notifications` and `unreadNotifications` without `()`

```
auth()->guard('admin')->user()->notifications
//
auth()->guard('admin')->user()->unreadNotifications
```

When using `()` on relationships you are always retrieving a `Eloquent` or `Query` Builder instance

Comment: Thanks. I missed that part. It’s notifications without the brackets